# Get a parameter of an agent of a specific population in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have the following problem and would love to get some help.
Situation:

Agent A is in population X, agent B is in population Y

I want to set the variable varA of agent A to varB of agent B. Agent A and agent B are in different populations X and Y, but agent B is the only agent in population B which parameter par1 equals to the parameter par1 of agent A.

I'm trying to write that into a function, which is called whenever I need to update that specific parameter, but could not succeed in doing so.

Any help is really appreciated.

Best Heinz_S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say the names of your populations are popX and popY... Initially varA is different than varB, and you want to make them equal according to their match on the parameter par1

The following function will match all the agents in your populations that have equal par1 and make varA equal to varB in all the cases. You can probably use stream() more efficiently... but I don't know how.

```
for(int i=0;i<popX.size();i++){
    for(int j=0;j<popY.size();j++){
        if(popX.get(i).par1==popY.get(j).par1){
            popX.get(i).varA=popY.get(j).varB;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I could get my code working with this solution.